# WAITFOR for an action inside procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have two procedures. One is called after another sequentially.

**Step 1:** App(Java) will Call `Proc1`

```
create procedure proc1
as
begin 
stmt 1
stmt 2
stmt 3
stmt 4 -- select query (result)
end
```

**Step 2 :** Our application (Java) will capture the result and manipulate the data and it will updated in another table called `result_table`

**Step 3 :** App(Java) Call `Proc2`

```
create procedure Proc2
as
begin 
stmt 1
stmt 2
stmt 3
stmt 5 -- this step uses result_table
stmt 6
end
```

As you can see in both procedures first three statements are same. So I am planning to combine both the procedures together to avoid duplication of codes. something like

```
create procedure proc1
as
begin 
stmt 1
stmt 2
stmt 3
stmt 4 -- select query (result)
--- App(Java) will capture the result and process it 
--- wait until the app completes the changes then proceed to stmt 5
stmt 5 
stmt 6
end
```

Here the tricky part is waiting for the application to complete the process and proceed with step 5. Can we wait for some signal or anything like that inside a procedures. Any ideas ?

Did searched the forum didn't get any proper answers.

Comment: Using CLR stored procedures I would guess. Leverage the .NET framework to do the waiting for that signal. Depends on what that signal is of course...

Comment: Good old-fashioned polling is an option (call `WAITFOR DELAY` in a loop). You could also put a message in a service broker queue and `RECEIVE` that (which, incidentally, is the only other thing allowed in a `WAITFOR`).

Comment: Our app code is using `Java`. Unfortunately there are no .NET or C# developers available here :/. Can we have this handled in Database ?

Comment: I think for your query there is no need to use waitfor option

Comment: Another option (which is fairly lame, but simple) is to use [`sp_getapplock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189823) as a waiting mechanism: acquire the lock in your application (in a new session) before executing `proc1`, acquire it in `proc1` before `stmt5`, release the lock in the application when you're done processing.

Comment: Well, if you can get your procesing app to send a message to the queue when it is done processing, you can use the advice given by Jeroen. You should probably describe how the processing app signals when the processing is done... Is it a program your company is developing and you have control over it? Is it an external program that has only limited ways of communicating (eg by putting a `im-done-processing-file` somewhere)?

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Will read about `sp_getapplock`

Comment: @JeroenMostert (about sp_getapplock) That seems rather tedious, considering it's a different application that does the processing. There would have to be communication between the two outside of SQL Server to synchronize these steps. I think your first advice is best, if both the applications are developed by Prdp's company a queue would be practical.

Comment: @TT.: I don't read more than one one application in this story. It just happens to want to put execution of a procedure "on hold". The two applications synchronizing are the user app and SQL Server. But yes, if there are two separate processes involved outside SQL Server, I don't recommend `sp_getapplock` because you also need a way to communicate the lock name (or, even more lamely, always use the same one and accept it doesn't scale).

Comment: @JeroenMostert From the last SP: `---App will capture the result and process it --- wait until the app completes the changes then proceed to stmt 5`. That app is a different app from the one executing the SP, at least that's what I'm thinking.

Comment: @TT. - No App is the one executing the `SP` the control will sent back to the same app

Comment: `RAISERROR WITH NOWAIT` will send a message back to the client immediately (without stopping the SP). If you can sink that event in Java that will solve your problem. I'm not familiar with the Java database API though.

Comment: @Prdp So you mean two different threads in the same app? I'm not getting the architecture from your question tbh. Perhaps a flow of control diagram with all apps/threads/modules would help make the architecture more clear. If you meant to say `A → SQL Server (stmt1-4) → A (processing) → SQL Server (stmt 5-6) → A`, you could create two stored procedures, no?

Comment: @TT. - Exactly.. `A → SQL Server (stmt1-4) → A (processing) → SQL Server (stmt 5-6) → A`.. I already have two procedures I just dont want to duplicate the codes

Comment: @Prdp The thing I'm thinking about: New SP `proc3= stmt 1-3`. Then `proc1= proc3 + stmt 4`, `proc2= proc3 + stmt 5-6`.

Comment: If your only problem is duplicating the *code* (as opposed to the execution of the code) you can just ship the duplicated code off to a new sproc and `EXEC` that from other places. You may need to solve the problem of sharing data, but there are [ways for that](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [GO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) keyword between stmt 4 and 5 and use [IF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) condition to check for the result_table.

Comment: You can't use GO in stored procedures. From that link: *GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.*